# substr in awk statement from xml parse

Tags: xml, bash, awk, xml-parsing, substr

Link to the original question: [bash script extract XML data into column format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686172/bash-script-extract-xml-data-into-column-format) and now for a modification and explanation ->

Something within this line of code is not correct and I believe it is with the substr portion and that would be because I don't have a full understanding and would like to learn HOW better to understand it. Yes I have looked at documentation and its not fully clicking. A couple examples as well as an answer would really be helpful.

```
awk -F'[<>]' 'BEGIN{a["STKPR"]="Prod";a["STKSVBLKU"]="Prod";a["STKSVBLOCK"]="Prod";a["STKSVBLK2"]="Test";} /Name/{name=$3; type=a[substr(name,length(name))]; if (length(type)==0) type="Test";} /SessionHost/+/Host/{print type, name, $3;}'|sort -u
```

This bit here:

```
type=a[substr(name,length(name))]; if (length(type)==0) type="Test";
```

Here is the xml format which each bit is a block for each host that contains the hostname and IP.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Connection>
  <ConnectionType>Putty</ConnectionType>
  <CreatedBy>Someone</CreatedBy>
  <CreationDateTime>2014-10-27T11:53:32.0157492-04:00</CreationDateTime>
  <CredentialConnectionID>9F3C3BCF-068A-4927-B996-CA52154CAE3B</CredentialConnectionID>
  <Description>Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 (64-bit)</Description>
  <Events>
    <OpenCommentPrompt>true</OpenCommentPrompt>
    <WarnIfAlreadyOpened>true</WarnIfAlreadyOpened>
  </Events>
  <Group>PATH/TO/GROUP/NAME</Group>
  <ID>f2007f03-3b33-47d3-8335-ffd84ccc0e6b</ID>
  <MetaInformation />
  <Name>STKSPRDAPP01111</Name>
  <OpenEmbedded>true</OpenEmbedded>
  <PinEmbeddedMode>False</PinEmbeddedMode>
  <Putty>
    <AlwaysAskForPassword>true</AlwaysAskForPassword>
    <Domain>DOMAIN</Domain>
    <FontSize>12</FontSize>
    <Host>10.0.0.111</Host>
    <Port>22</Port>
    <PortFowardingArray />
    <TelnetEncoding>IBM437</TelnetEncoding>
  </Putty>
  <Stamp>85407098-127d-4d3c-b7fa-8f174cb1e3bd</Stamp>
  <SubMode>2</SubMode>
  <TemplateName>SSH-PerUserCreds</TemplateName>
</Connection>
```

What I want to do is similar to the referenced link above. But here I want to match -->

```
BEGIN{a["STKPR"]="Prod";a["STKSVBLKU"]="Prod";a["STKSVBLOCK"]="Prod";a["STKSVBLK2"]="Test";
```

and all of the rest as Test. Best to read the previous post to help make this one more understandable. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your keys here are of different length, the `substr` approach is less than optimal.  Try:

```
awk -F'[<>]' '/Name/{n=$3;t="Test"; if(n ~ /^STKPR/) t="Prod"; if (n ~/^STKSVBLKU/) t="Prod"; if (n ~/^STKSVBLOCK/) t="Prod"} /SessionHost/+/Host/{print t, n, $3;}' sample.xml |sort -u
Test STKSPRDAPP01111 10.0.0.111
```

#### How It Works

In this case, the type, denoted by `t`, is set according to a series of `if` statements.  From the above code, they are:

```
t="Test"
if (n ~ /^STKPR/) t="Prod"
if (n ~ /^STKSVBLKU/) t="Prod" 
if (n ~ /^STKSVBLOCK/) t="Prod"
```

By setting `t="Test"`, `Test` becomes the default: the type will be `Test` unless another statement matches.  If of the following statements looks at the string that begins the host name and, if there is a match, sets type `t` to a new value.  (When a regular expression begins with `^`, that means that what follows must match at the beginning of the string.)

#### Alternative using fancier regular expressions

Since the above three `if` statements are all for the `Prod` type, the three of them could, if you preferred, be rearranged to:

```
t="Test"
if (n ~ /^STK(PR|SVBLKU|SVBLOCK)/) t="Prod"
```

(metalcated: Fixed unmatched parentheses bracket)

Comment: I like the second solution better and it can be more in more ways much more easily. Again... thank you for the solution and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The `substr` portion produces a string containing the last character of the string.  This is because it is taking a substring of string `name` starting at the position `length(name)` going to the end of the string, and because `substr` is indexed starting at 1.

To match whole strings you can use your variable `name` rather than processing it with `substr`.

```
/Name/ { name=$3; type=a[name]; if (length(type)==0) type="Test"; }
```